# Wheatstone bridge connected to op-amp: confusion about Vout formula

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-divider, wheatstone-bridge

I am not sure when the correct formula for Vout is Vout = G(VA - VB) or Vout = -G(VA - VB).

[image]

Can you explain the difference between these two examples? The circuits and the formulas provided are from my textbook, yet I struggle to understand how the formula for Vout ​is derived in each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in Spehro's answer you need to assume that the circuit diagram examples are actually simplified versions of a bridge amplifier, some details are not being shown, (for e.g.: feedback, bias, gain resistors, etc.).

In both examples it is shown that the resistive sensor located at the bottom right increases, as shown by the (R+dR) , so typically the voltage at Point A will be greater than point B. In bridge jargon with this arrangement you could label point A as the +Signal connection and point B as the -Signal connection.

So starting with the example diagram 2 you have the +Signal output to +input of the amplifier and the -Signal to the -input of the amplifier, (++, --). Therefore the amplifier output would be G(VA-VB).

In example diagram 1 you have the bridge outputs connected in reverse, the +Signal connects to the -input and the -Signal to the +input, (+-, -+). So in this case the amplifier output is also reversed giving the negated output of -G(VA-VB).

Comment: When you're talking about Wheatstone Bridge Amplifiers, "sense" often applies to high-impendence sense pathways for the POWER SUPPLIES, in order to servo them at the command.

Comment: @Scott - OK, in a 4 wire excitation setup to a wheatstone bridge extra connections (if used), for "Sensing" the excitation voltage can be labeled as the +-Sense lines. In this case the center bridge connections can be labeled as +Signal and -Signal. As shown the example diagrams do not include these extra excitation sense lines. Regardless, the text in the above answer is revised.

Answer (score 0):

The amplifier is probably not a conventional op-amp. It might be an instrumentation amplifier with gain G. In reality there also needs to be some way to maintain the inputs within common mode range of the amplifier, so maybe there's one side of the voltage source grounded.

In any case, if the instrumentation amplifier is biased so that it is functioning properly, the output voltage of the instrumentation amplifier will be +G(Va-Vb) if Va is connected to the non-inverting input "+" and Vb is connected to the inverting input "-". If the opposite is true, then the output will be -G(Va-Vb).

If it was an op-amp, there is no negative feedback, so G will be very large, and the output will be railed at the positive supply voltage if Va > Vb and at the negative supply voltage if Va < Vb.